# Does automator work when screensaver is active

Tags: mojave, automator, screensaver

I have set a function in automator that opens a website everyday in specific time (after midnight basically). So I decided to leave mac turned on to let automator work. Instead I trigger screensaver with login screen. I wonder if the automator execute my command during active screensaver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if the automator execute my command during active screensaver?

Yes, the automator action will execute as long as you Mac is not asleep.